# How to share EGLImageKHR object between different devices

Tags: c++, opengl, egl

I am trying to save screenshot of a qml quick controls application on a platform (running QT on wayland) by using native opengl functions .What I am doing is that using a RGB color render buffer with eglCreateImageKHR function and then send the EGLImageKHR void pointer to another device through Qt socket communication. I can successfully create EGLImage that means that there is no error from eglGetError function . For testing the EGLImageKHR object correctness, I bind it to another framebuffer by using glEglImageTargetRenderbufferStorageOES on the same process and read the pixel from glReadPixel function , create a png file from read buffer and observed that correct png is created with correct colors.

After that I tried to send this EGLImageKHR void pointer to another device or process and then create some png from the sended EGLImageKHR object and I do not see correct colored png ,only have a noise on the png.

Following is the code sample to create the EGLImageKHR from render buffer and then saving a tga_file from EGLImageKHR.

```
// create render buffer and bind it to a framebuffer
glGenRenderbuffers( 1, &renderBuffer );
glBindRenderbuffer( GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer );
glRenderbufferStorage( GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_RGB, mWinWidth, mWinHeight );
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0); //mwindow->openglContext()->defaultFramebufferObject());

if (glGetError()==GL_NO_ERROR)
{
//qDebug() << "Render buff storage is OK" << glGetError();
}
else
{
qDebug() << "Render buff storage error is " << glGetError();
}

glGenFramebuffers( 1, &frameBuffer );
glBindFramebuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
glFramebufferRenderbuffer( GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);

//printFramebufferInfo(frameBuffer);
if( glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
{
qDebug() << "Framebuffer error is " << glGetError();
}
else
{
//qDebug() << "Framebuffer is OK" << glGetError();
}

// create EGLImageKHR object
mWinWidth = mwindow->width();
mWinHeight = mwindow->height();

glGetIntegerv(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, &rowPack);
glPixelStorei(GL_PACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER,mwindow->openglContext()->defaultFramebufferObject());
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER,frameBuffer);
glBlitFramebuffer(0, 0, mWinWidth, mWinHeight, 0, 0, mWinWidth, mWinHeight, GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT, GL_NEAREST);

m_display = reinterpret_cast<egldisplay>(reinterpret_cast<void*>(QGuiApplication::platformNativeInterface()->nativeResourceForIntegration("egldisplay")));
m_context = QGuiApplication::platformNativeInterface()->nativeResourceForContext("eglcontext", mwindow->openglContext());

mImage = CreateImageKHR(m_display,m_context, EGL_GL_RENDERBUFFER_KHR,reinterpret_cast<eglclientbuffer>(renderBuffer), nullptr);

if (mImage == EGL_NO_IMAGE_KHR)
{
qDebug("failed to make image from target buffer: %s", get_egl_error());
return -1;
}

int size = mWinWidth * mWinHeight * 3;
sendEglImage(size);
glDeleteRenderbuffers(1,&renderBuffer);
renderBuffer = 0;
glDeleteFramebuffers(1,&frameBuffer);
frameBuffer = 0;

// send EGLImageKHR to client
sendEglImage(int size)
{
if (SenderSocket != NULL)
{
QByteArray data;
data.append(reinterpret_cast<const char*="">(mImage),size);
//data.append(reinterpret_cast<qbytearray *="">(mImage));
QDataStream out(&data, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
out.setDevice(SenderSocket);
out << data;
//qDebug() << "func " << __FUNCTION__ << "line" << __LINE__;
qDebug() << "func " << __FUNCTION__ << "line" << __LINE__ << "data size" << data.size();
}

QImage testImg((uchar *)mImage,640,480,QImage::Format_RGB888, nullptr, nullptr);
if(testImg.save("server.png"))
qDebug() << "Successfully saved image" << testImg;

DestroyImageKHR(m_display,mImage);
mImage = 0;
}

// Another approach to create a tga_file from EGLImageKHR is
FILE *out = fopen("tga_file", "w");
short TGAhead[] = {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 640, 480, 24};
fwrite(&TGAhead, sizeof(TGAhead), 1, out);
fwrite(mImage, mWinWidth * mWinHeight*3, 1, out);
fflush(out);
fclose(out);

// One more different trial

   int bufSize = mWinHeight * mWinWidth*3;

   unsigned char * trialBuff = new unsigned char[bufSize];

   memcpy(trialBuff,khrImage,bufSize);

   FILE *out = fopen("dada.txt", "w");

   fwrite(trialBuff, bufSize, 1, out);

   fflush(out);

   fsync(fileno(out));

   fclose(out);

   delete [] trialBuff;
```

So When I try to create a png with QImage or with fwrite from EGLImageKHR object, I do not get a valid png or tga_file.

Note that I do not want to use glReadPixels function since it is causing high cpu load.
Is there any idea how I can create some png file from EGLImageKHR and How I can send it to another device ?

Comment: None of your attempts make any sense. `EGLImage*` is just a pointer in the address spcae of your process, and sharing this address with another process (on the same device or another) is never going to work. Also, you can't treat it as an pointer to an array of RGB data, it is only an opaque handle. "Note that I do not want to use `glReadPixels` function since it is causing high cpu load." But that's the only way to do it, and it actually doesn't cause high CPU load. You just need to do a proper asynchronous readback.

Comment: Hello @derhass, Thank you for the feedback.In fact I have used EGLImageKHR object as binding it to dma buf and used it on the same device on two different process.I was thinking that EGLImageKHR is a 2D byte array from documentation but observed that I misunderstand. Do you have an example of asynchronous readback ? Also what about using Pixel buffer object ?

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented another function to run glReadPixels in asynchronous way.Following is the code snippet:

```
void createPixelBO()
{
    glGenBuffers(PBO_COUNT,pboIds);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER,pboIds[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_size, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER,pboIds[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_size, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
    
    mWinWidth = mwindow->width();
    mWinHeight = mwindow->height();
    pbo_size = mWinHeight * mWinWidth *3;
    pixels = new unsigned char[pbo_size];
}

void runPixelBO()
{
    static int index = 0;
    int nextIndex = 0;                  // pbo index used for next frame
    index = (index + 1) % 2;
    nextIndex = (index + 1) % 2;

    createPixelBO();
    memset(pixels,0,pbo_size);
    glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pboIds[index]);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, mWinWidth, mWinHeight, GL_BGR, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pboIds[nextIndex]);

    GLubyte *ptr = (GLubyte*)glMapBufferRange(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0, pbo_size, GL_MAP_READ_BIT);

    if (ptr)
    {
        memcpy(pixels, ptr, pbo_size);

        FILE   *out = fopen("pbo", "w");
        short  TGAhead[] = {0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 640, 480, 24};
        fwrite(&TGAhead, sizeof(TGAhead), 1, out);
        fwrite(pixels,  pbo_size, 1, out);
        fflush(out);
        fclose(out);

        glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
        glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
        glDeleteBuffers(PBO_COUNT, pboIds);
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "glMapBufferRange error";
    }
}
```

CPU consumption is OK on nvidia platform but still really high on Intel.
Any idea what might be the reason?

Regards